# Saving a Tree With Frost Damage

Tags: trees, frost, recovery

I have a friend who left a Redwood (Sequoiadendron giganteum) sapling out in the cold and snow a few months ago. It's still alive- it has some green needles still- but it's slowly getting browner and browner. What can be done to revitalize it?

It's about 8 inches tall, and under 6 months old. It's been in its current pot for about 2 months.

[image: Picture of the tree]
Here's a picture of the tree. It looks like it's planted in sand, which would be bad, but it's an even mixture of sand, potting soil, and mulch. The soil and mulch has just been washed below the sand.

Comment: water it and wait, trees have amazing recovery powers but need time to do so.  Gardeners often lack patience...

Comment: Well, it's been a few months of consistently watering the right amount now, and there hasn't been any visible improvement... How long should he expect recovery to take?

Comment: I would wait until the end of summer.  If no growth happens by then the plant is probably dead. How about a pictures of the plant?

Comment: I'll try to get some today and edit them into the question.

Comment: I just added a picture.

Comment: Looks like a going concern to me. I think it is well worth waiting to see if you get some new growth

Comment: Ok. I'll let my friend know, and keep this question updated as it changes. Thank you!

Comment: Keep uniformly moist.

Comment: BTW, do we have news. Did the redwood survive the summer?

Comment: Yes, it survived well. It was kept outside over the winter and turned dark green, which I thought might be bad, but it's more than doubled its height, so I think it's alright.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think frost will damage it.

I noticed that on spring the Redwood tend to brownish, but later in end spring it will return green (blue green at the beginning).

Comment: Thank you. If you can provide some references, or outside evidence of credibility, I'll mark this as the answer.